# php call certain html elements and make a condition

Tags: php, html, preg-match

I'm just new with php and recently I was try to make a use of `preg_match_all()`.

source: http//:test.com

```
 <tr>
    <td class="build">
    <a id="viewBuild:TEST-TESTAUTO">Sample - Regression 01</a>
    </td>
    <td class="planKeySection Successful">
    <a id="statusSectionTEST-TESTAUTO" class="statusIcon">
    <span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-approve" title="build succeeded">
    </a>


<tr>
<td class="build">
<a id="viewBuild:TEST-TESTAUTO02">Sample - Regression 02</a>
</td>
<td class="planKeySection Successful">
<a id="statusSectionTEST-TESTAUTO02" class="statusIcon">
<span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-approve" title="build succeeded">
</a>
```

This code doesn't work:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http//:test.com');

if(preg_match_all( "'/<tr>[1]<span class=\"aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-approve\"><\/tr>/isU'", $content)) 
    echo "done";
}else{
    echo "fail";
}

if(preg_match_all( "'/<tr>[2]<span class=\"aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-approve\"><\/tr>/isU'", $content)) 
    echo "done";
}else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

as you can see above, I'm trying to get a certain element on above source and make a condition that if it's `<span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-approve">` then it will echo "done" but all I get is "fail".

Comment: http//:test.com is wrong. The : is misplaced Has to be http://test.com

Answer (score 0):

```
if(count(preg_match_all($pattern, $content))>0)
```

or

```
if(preg_match($pattern, $content))
```

What you also have to do is fix the URL: it has to be `http://test.com` not `http//:test.com`

Comment: ^sorry bout the URL, is just a made up. I was using a different one. Anyway I'll try the code above. Hope it works. Thanks

Comment: I was wondering, can I also call this tags in just one preg_match? <a id="statusSectionTEST-TESTAUTO02" class="statusIcon">
<span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-approve" title="build succeeded">
</a> basically, I want to preg match, if id=statusSectionTEST-TESTAUTO02 and class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-approve" then echo done, else fail. But not sure how im going to write it lol

Answer (score 0):

To match the first substring use:

`~id="statusSectionTEST-TESTAUTO" class="statusIcon">\s+<span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-approve"~`

To match the second substring use:

`~id="statusSectionTEST-TESTAUTO02" class="statusIcon">\s+<span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-approve"~`

The only adjust that I made to the literal string to create the pattern was `\s+` so that white-space characters don't cause an undesired mismatch.

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hUChUu/2) for the second pattern.

Code [(PHP Demo)](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5474c731be014db56fff1537ee87a61a26294e3a):

```
$content=' <tr>
    <td class="build">
    <a id="viewBuild:TEST-TESTAUTO">Sample - Regression 01</a>
    </td>
    <td class="planKeySection Successful">
    <a id="statusSectionTEST-TESTAUTO" class="statusIcon">
    <span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-approve" title="build succeeded">
    </a>


<tr>
<td class="build">
<a id="viewBuild:TEST-TESTAUTO02">Sample - Regression 02</a>
</td>
<td class="planKeySection Successful">
<a id="statusSectionTEST-TESTAUTO02" class="statusIcon">
<span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-approve" title="build succeeded">
</a>';

$pattern='~id="statusSectionTEST-TESTAUTO02" class="statusIcon">\s+<span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-approve"~';

if(preg_match($pattern,$content)){
    echo "found";
}else{
    echo "not found"; 
}
```

---

After re-reading your question, if you just want to capture `<span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-approve"`

Then `strpos()` will be sufficient:

Code ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6d439eaad14f2b56f8814038f71cddc08adaf6ac)):

```
$content=' <tr>
    <td class="build">
    <a id="viewBuild:TEST-TESTAUTO">Sample - Regression 01</a>
    </td>
    <td class="planKeySection Successful">
    <a id="statusSectionTEST-TESTAUTO" class="statusIcon">
    <span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-approve" title="build succeeded">
    </a>


<tr>
<td class="build">
<a id="viewBuild:TEST-TESTAUTO02">Sample - Regression 02</a>
</td>
<td class="planKeySection Successful">
<a id="statusSectionTEST-TESTAUTO02" class="statusIcon">
<span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-approve" title="build succeeded">
</a>';
$html ='<span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-approve"';

if(strpos($content,$html)!==false){
    echo "found";
}else{
    echo "not found"; 
}
```